# iOS - How reset to new state

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, reset, ipod

How would I go about setting an iOS project back to its default state via code? For example say I have a UITableView in storyboard and a ton of code to dictate how the table acts. How would I go about setting all the variables, the tableview, etc.. back to the state that it was when the app is opened(not resumed from the background)? 
Calling `[self viewDidLoad];` does NOT do it.

Thanks a LOT for any help.

-shredder

Answer (score 0):

You can do something to dealloc and then re-alloc your Controller. Then you'd be sure that the objects states you're reallocing are the initial ones.